# Rationale for the controller having the strong params whitelist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

In most Rails applications I've seen, the controller lists what attributes are or aren't permitted when submitting attributes.

```
class PersonsController < ApplicationController
  # rest of code
  def person_params
    params.require(:person).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

We don't see something like

```
# Hypothetical code only
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def my_param_whitelist
    [:name]
  end
end
```

Even though it'd seem more DRY to have the whitelist within the model class.

What is the rationale for the controller having the whitelist, rather than the models that are being modified?

Comment: It used to be like that before Rails4, see the intro notes of strong params http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/ :)

Comment: Adding to what uDaY said: Rails used to use `attr_accessible` and `attr_protected`: http://easyactiverecord.com/blog/2014/04/01/rails4-strong-parameters-and-the-attr-accessible-macro/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not thought about it too technically but here is a gut answer.

If you declare the permitted params in the model, yes, that keeps the code dry and you do not have to repeat yourself in every controller but that means every piece of code that has to communicate with the model has to go through the same white list.

If you keep the allowed params in the controller, however, you can allow different controllers to have their own whitelists.

For example, a user(UserController) may not be able to change his/her registered username/email but an admin(AdminController) may be able to do that. In such a case the UserController and AdminController have their own white list of permitted params.